# linux(Centos7) | I have two php.ini files

Tags: php, linux, centos, yum

I installed the apm on my Linux (Centos7) and i think i installed the php again with yum.

I have two php.ini file in the paths below.

```
/usr/loacal/php/bin/php.ini (v5.3)
/etc/php.ini (v5.4)


php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2015 21:17:27)

/usr/local/php/bin/php -v
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Mar  3 2016 11:17:12)
```

I have two versions of php on one server right now.

```
rpm -qa | grep php 

php-pdo-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-tcpdf-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
php-tidy-5.4.16-3.el7.x86_64
php-xml-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-12.el7.noarch
php-bcmath-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-gd-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-process-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-mysql-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.11-1.el7.noarch
```

I think this all files are installed with php(v5.4)
I can I remove these?

Can i just use the yum command again like below?

```
yum remove php
```

I'm so afraid that something happens when i do that.
Please let me know how to deal with this situation... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to remove anything. You can have as many versions of PHP installed as you like. The PATHS etc determine what actually gets used. To see what php binary is being used on command line use

```
which php
```

To see what php.ini file is being used by that binary use

```
php -i |grep "php.ini"
```

If you have the correct one then you're probably fine. To see what files will be remove by removing packages you can query the package to get the file list ie

```
rpm -ql php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
```

The common package should contain the php.ini file that gets installed. From these commands you should be able to work out if you want to remove anything.

Note, if you can, use the more modern versions of PHP that you have installed. PHP 5.3 and 5.4 are both considered old versions now and are no longer supported.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history